# How to check if the machine running on is 32 or 64 bit in C?

Tags: c

is there any preprocessor directive or other methods to check if the machine being run is 32 bit or 64 bit in C? I've tried googling this, but the problem with C is it brings up results for C#, C++, etc.. Also, I would prefer if this worked on Windows, Linux, and Mac.

Comment: You can try `sizeof(char*)`, in general the pointer-to-char has the machine-size. If it's 8, then your machine is 64 bit, if 4, then 32. This is probably not a portable solution, as the whole notion of "byte" is not standard C++.

Comment: What are you going to do with this information?

Comment: There is no rigorous definition of a "32-bit" or "64-bit" system.

Comment: @vsoftco that will report details about the machine that did the compilation (unless a cross-compiler is being used).  If a 32-bit .exe is run in 64-bit Windows , for example, it will still report `sizeof(char *) == 4`

Comment: I'm just toying around with LLVM, was hoping I could return the integer based on the cpu architecture, i.e 32 bit int on a 32 bit system, and 64 bit int on a 64 bit system.

Comment: @MattMcNabb indeed, that's actually what I thought OP wants... I see, if you really want to test whether your processor is indeed 64-bit, I then don't think it's possible with standard C/C++.

Comment: There are usually [non-core] functions provided by the operating system that will reveal such information; although such is not strictly tied to "the size of an integer".

Comment: @MattMcNabb ahh, that's a shame. Oh well, I'll just say an integer is 32 bit unless specified. Thanks for clearing it up though! :) Maybe one of you could answer saying that it's not possible or something? Or should I delete the question, but perhaps the information is valuable to someone.

Comment: I suspect what you will need to do is to ask the operating system for the environment of the machine and whether it is 64 bit or 32 bit. Compilation will only give results for the target hardware, 32 bit or 64 bit.  Preprocessor directives are handled by the Preprocessor and are not run time directives so the only thing Preprocessor could do is to tell you if the target is 64 bit or 32 bit.

Comment: With Linux I guess you'd just do a call to `uname()`.

Comment: Why not simply use `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` to determine the size of an integer?  Of course that indicates the size of an `int`.  But in the end - why do you want to know this information and what would you do with it?

Comment: @chux: `int` is generally 32 bits on both 32-bit 86 systems and x86_64 64-bit systems.

Comment: Are you trying to distinguish between x86 and x86_64 systems? If not, what exactly do *you* mean by "32-bit" and "64-bit" system?

Comment: @chux `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` won't work apparently.  Comments above suggest that the native word size is wanted here, perhaps even irrespective of whether the program is running in 16-bit mode, 32-bit mode, 64-bit mode, etc. If running on a 64-bit CPU, use a 64-bit integer type for example. I don't think this had any practical purpose at the moment: "I'm just toying with LLVM, [and I] was hoping I could return the integer based on the cpu architecture, i.e 32 bit int on a 32 bit system, and 64 bit int on a 64 bit system."

Comment: If you compile the program as 64 bits, it cannot run on 32-bit system, and other 64-bit systems, so checking if the system is 32 or 64 bits is pointless. If you compile the program as 32 bits, it cannot use 64-bit registers, so returning a 64-bit value will always twice the time used to store a 32-bit value regardless of system you're running on, 32 or 64 bits. So why do you need to return 64-bit values on 64-bit systems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious way to do this at run time.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     printf("%d bits\n", (int)(CHAR_BIT * sizeof(void *)));
     return 0;
}
```

Technically, this is not 100% guaranteed to work.   Practically, this will work with most modern compilers - it is unusual for a void pointer to be represented using a number of bits that differs from that of the underlying system architecture.

To do a compile time check, there is no standard way.   It is necessary to resort to macros that are specific to your compiler/preprocessor.   You will therefore need to read relevant documentation.

Comment: This checks whether the program was compiled as a 32 or 64-bit app. **It doesn't show the bitness of the OS you're running on**

Answer (score 2):

This isn't necessarily indicative of the machine that is running (read: not true when cross-compiling), but there are some preprocessor directives.

You can determine 32/64 bit from the architecture, the most common ones are:

```
// 64-bit
__x86_64__

// 32-bit
__i386__ ... __i686__
```

You can read a whole bunch of these here, for nearly any modernish processor:

http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Architectures/

Answer (score 2):

For Linux and OS X:

```
#include <sys/utsname.h>

struct utsname a;
uname (&a);
```

`a->machine` will be the string x86_64 on 64bit Intel machines, probably i586 or i686 on 32bit. You could do conditional compiling for these and whatever Windows uses.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following preprocessor directives to check if the machine is `x86_64` in C. If it is `64-bit` it sets the `#define BUILD_64` flag. You then just check `#ifdef BUILD_64` as the test throughout your code:

```
#if defined(__LP64__) || defined(_LP64)
# define BUILD_64   1
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If this worked on Windows, I have some method.

1. check whether the reg `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node` exists;
2. check whether the file `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` exists;
3. use Windows API(`IsWow64Process`), please read [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: `IsWow64Process` presumably returns false for 32-bit processes on 32-bit Windows.